# Can I take a deduction for expenses associated with an investment property I didn't buy?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property

I own a couple of rental homes that are very cash flow positive, so I was looking to buy another investment property. I found a duplex and put a contract on it, but based on the inspector's report I backed out of the deal and did not purchase it.

Is the cost of the inspection (~$500) deductible against my income from the other properties I own? What about the deposit ($100) I gave up by backing out during the option period?

Comment: Do you report your rentals on schedule E or schedule C?

Comment: Why would you think C? With 2 properties, he's not a full time RE investor.

Comment: I use Schedule E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot generally deduct these expenses. These are investigatory expenses that you made before acquiring the property. Had you acquired it - they would be added to the basis as part of the closing costs, but since you actually have not purchased an asset - you have nothing to add to the basis of. This has been the settled law after a Tax Court decision since 1931.

Comment: Does your answer change if he's a professional RE investor? i.e. more than 750hrs/yr & major job?

Comment: Wouldn't these be allowed as "investment expenses" under the miscellaneous itemized expenses subject to the 2% floor, if there's nowhere else specific to report them?  These are expenses incurred to research and decide on an investment.   I am not certain which is why I didn't put in my own answer.

Comment: And could the expired option be reported as a $100 loss on schedule D?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer for professional investor as you described this would be a business expense. Professional investor treats assets as inventory and doesn't set up a new business for each asset. The OP does, since he said he's a retail (Schedule E) investor.

Comment: @user662852 no, because no investment was made. Similarly, no loss since no asset was disposed of. There was no expired option. He signed a contract and backed out of it.

Comment: Thx. Your answer was complete, that extra just helped to understand if/when it might be a real deduction.